# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `verified' for "a ten digit phone number":String)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a active record called **PhoneNumber** which has `phone_number`an integer and `verified` a boolean column. So I am trying pass ac condition in `js.erb` template something like this:

```
$('#hidden_phone_number').val('<%= @phone_number.phone_number %>' )
<% if @phone_number.phone_number.verified %>
    <%= puts "Hello world"%>
<%else%>
    $('#send-pin').hide()
    $('#verify-pin').fadeToggle()
    $('#pin').focus()
<%end%>
```

First I checked for the value of`@phone_number.phone_number`. It is giving value. And it's verified boolean is `true`. So when I did above changes in the code and executed it is giving error at :

`<% if @phone_number.phone_number.verified %>` saying

`ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method`verified' for "10 digit phone number":String):`

I tried converting using `to_i`. Still same error. How can I fix this?

Comment: You probably mean `if @phone_number.phone_number && @phone_number.verified`

Answer (score 1):

They're two separate fields.

It's `@phone_number.phone_number` for the actual phone number which is a string

It's`@phone_number.verified` for whether the number is verified which is a boolean

`@phone_number.phone_number.verified` is running method `#verified` on a String object, and there's no such method.